# SSRS hide a row where a expression field value is blank

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression

I have a field in my SSRS report that derives a value based on an expression.  The expressions is a simple Lookup between 2 datasets and is working fine. It does return some NULL values and what I would like to do is not display the rows where the expression produces a NULL value. I know how to do this on a field that is not based on an expression but not on a field that is.  Anyone know how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, it will be something like the expression below on the Hidden property of whatever it is you are trying to hide/show.

`=IIf(IsNothing(<your Lookup expression>), True, False)`

Add any other checking in there too, if need be.

UPDATE:

To make this work on the entire row. Right-click on a row header in design mode, and choose Row Visibility... Click *Show or hide based on an expression*. Add the expression you now have in there.

Comment: Don't forget if you place this in the Hidden property the true evaluates to "yes it will hide" sometimes this can be confusing...

Comment: This expression did the trick: =IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!CUSIP.Value, Fields!CUSIP.Value, Fields!CUSIP.Value, "MonthEnd")),True, False)  the formatting of the report look off now as the rows are removed but the rows that have values in them are not together.  Thanks

Comment: @KDouglas Added more to this to handle that issue.